# The nomenclature behind “Diacetonamine”

Tags: organic-chemistry, nomenclature, amines

Please explain how the name “[Diacetonamine](http://www.chemspider.com/Chemical-Structure.62570.html)” can be found by looking at the formula:  $$\ce{(CH3)2C(NH2)CH2C(O)CH3}$$

[image: Diacetonamine]

Why is it called “Diaceto” if there only one $\ce{-C(O)CH3}$ group?

Comment: Your formula doesn't show diacetonamine; it shows 4-amino-4-methylpentan-2-one.

Comment: I’ve added a picture - did I write the formula down wrong?

Comment: Isn’t there only 1 “aceto-“ group then why is it called diacetoamine?

Comment: I think I understand what you mean. I edited your question a bit (added a reference to ChemSpider to backup your doubt; fixed a typo in "Diaceton**e**amine") and cast a vote to reopen. But Loong is right, diacetonamine is a different compound, I think it should have $\ce{NH(CH2C(O)CH3)2}$ formula.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This compound is obtained by reaction of two molecules of acetone and one molecule of ammonia , so it is named diacetone amine

Comment: So the name cant be obtained by just looking at the compound's formula as it is? (if we don't know how it's formed)

Answer (score 3):

It's likely a trivial name constructed in a similar way like its alcohol analogue $\ce{(CH3)2C(OH)CH2COCH3}$ 4-hydroxy-4-methylpentan-2-one, better known as “[diacetone alcohol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diacetone_alcohol)”, which is prepared by dimerization condensation of acetone.